# Delphi Bluetooth Discovery Problem with Ios (13.3)

Tags: ios, delphi, bluetooth, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a problem.

The TBluetoothLE.DiscoverDevices ()
line crashes in the latest versions of IOS(13.3).

I tried it with Device Multi-Device Samples\Sensors and Services\Bluetooth, the ExploreDevicesLE app and also my own code. There is a problem in both of them.

No problem on all android versions and previous ios version.

> Delphi version -> 10.3.3
>
> IPAD version ->   updated IOS 13.3

Comment: what delphi version are you using? Please edit your question and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. I added version info. Thank you.

Comment: I added the tag for you, no need to put it in the question

Comment: Chances are high that there is a compatibility issue with the latest IOS version, you will need to raise an issue with Embarcadero.

Comment: It needs a NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key in the Version Info of Project Options, but it still crashes for me, too. More later..

Comment: yes, it works. Thanks.. @DaveNottage